# Как работать с несколькими переменными в цикле for?

Tags: python, циклы, for, переменные, while

Мне надо вызвать одну и туже команду для множества переменных названия которых отличаются лишь одной цифрой. Могу ли я это сделать в цикле?

У меня есть 12 переменных с названиями pushButton_1, pushButton_2 и т.д. Для всех них мне нужно запустить вот такой метод "pushButton_1.setIcon(icon)". Кажется логичным написать цикл вида:

```
For i in range(1, 13):
    pushButton_+str(i).setIcon(icon)
```

Но очевидно что так не получится, потому что в таком случае "i" будет стараться прибавить к переменной "pushButton_" которой не существует. Будет ошибка. А есть ли возможность сделать это правильно?

Comment: Заведите массив `pushButtons = []`, заполните его (`pushButtons.append(...)`) и работайте с ним: `pushButtons[i].setIcon(icon)`.

Comment: python хранит переменные в словаре, где ключи - это имена переменных в формате строки. обратится к этому словарю можно, например, с помощью встроенной функции `vars()`, примерно так `vars()[f'button_{i}']`. но вариант с массивом конечно предпочтительнее.

Comment: @SergFSM, лучше не советовать новичкам такие костыли